Serializing typescript tuples
Is there a more robust/typed way of traversing Tuple types? My current approach feels too hacky because resolvedTypeArguments appears to be an internal property:
const getSerializedType = (myType: ts.Type, checker: ts.TypeChecker) => {

  if (checker.isArrayType(myType)) {

    const itemType = checker.getTypeArguments(myType as ts.TypeReference)[0];

    if (itemType && checker.isTupleType(itemType)) {
      const elements =
        (itemType as any).resolvedTypeArguments?.map((e: ts.Type) => {
          return getSerializedType(e, checker);
        }) ?? [];

      return {
        type: "tuple",
        elements,
      };
    }
    // ... normal array

  }
  // ... other types
}

